# Fuzziness on 3 letter words

Tags: elasticsearch

What kind of analyzers would you implement in Elasticsearch for searching book titles.

The requirements are that there must be fuzziness and there are word that are 3 letters.

I'm not going to include code because I would like to get a fresh insight.
But the problem I am having is that when I search 3 letters words wrong,
Say I type "dns" and there is a document with a field "dna" then I will get 
kindness or something that has dns in the word.

Answer (score 3):

I believe to solve your problem you can use the fuzziness field in your fuzzy query, this will let you set the maximum edit distance so long words will not get matched when your input is a very small word.

```
{
"fuzzy" : {
    "user" : {
        "value" :         "ki",
        "fuzziness" :     2,
        "prefix_length" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

The above query would match all 3 letter words which start with the letter 'k' and all 4 letter words which start with the letters 'ki'. A fuzziness of 2 means that any 2 edits are allowed i.e. either change 'i' to another letter and then add another letter or add two more letter while keeping 'ki'. The prefix length tells elasticsearch how much of the query needs to be exactly matched before the fuzziness can take over.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html